# Error ORA-01722: Invalid use of Number in Select with Xmlagg / Xmlelement

Tags: xml, oracle, select, string-concatenation, ora-01722

I am getting the above error for the following query - only after it runs already for about 30 min.
**Since I only get the error after this time I was wondering if it is caused by something towards the end of the query, e.g. the ** `.EXTRACT` **?**

I tried using `TO_CHAR` and `NVL` for all items in the Xmlelement which didn't help either.

However, when I use the same structure (Rtrim / Xmlagg / Xmlelement) separately for columns 2 to 6 then it works fine (it just doesn't help me that way).
Listagg works too but doesn't allow enough characters.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

**Error message:**

> ORA-01722 ... invalid use of a NUMBER.

**My query:**

```
SELECT
    a.column1 AS ID
    , RTRIM
        (
            XMLAGG
                (
                    XMLELEMENT
                    (
                        e, 'Column2: ' || b.column2 || 
                        'Column3: ' || SUBSTR(c.column3, 1, 50) || '...' || 
                        'Column4: ' || b.column4 || 
                        'Column5: ' || TO_CHAR(b.column5, 'FM9,990.00') || 
                        'Column6: ' || TO_CHAR(b.column6, 'FM9,990.00') || 
                        '---'
                    ) ORDER BY b.column2
                ).EXTRACT('//text()'), ','
        ) AS AD
    , TO_CHAR(b.column7, 'FM9,990.00') AS GN
    , TO_CHAR(b.column8, 'FM9,990.00') AS GU
    , TO_CHAR((b.column7 + b.column8), 'FM9,990.00') AS GB
FROM
    /* ... */
```

Could it be possible that the problem here is that I use `','` as the EXTRACT separator but might also have commas somewhere within my column values ?

**Update:**
When I take out the lines for columns 5 and 6 it works. Column 4 is number format too so it can't be caused by the format.

Any help is much appreciated,
Mike

Comment: What are the data types of all the columns - particularly (if running just the XMLAgg part works for *all* rows, not just say the fist 50 in grid output) columns 6 and 7? What happens if you only remove the `extract()`? If all those you are passing in to `to_char()` are really numbers, sample data that shows the problem might help (but then, might also tell you what is wrong...)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks. Columns 1 to 3 are VARCHAR2, columns 4 to 8 are NUMBER format. I wonder if my problem is that there may be commas in the column values as well as I use ',' for the Extract. Bu then again it runs fine if I write Rtrim / Xmlagg / Xmlelement ... separately for each column.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Update: When I take out the lines for columns 5 and 6 it works. Column 4 is number format too so it can't be caused by the format.